# How a server keeps running?

Tags: server, operating-system

My question might seem lame, but I am asking this out of curiosity. When we write a standalone java program , it gets executed and then gets terminated. But in socket programming, we create a while true loop, under which  it continuously listens for a request. Is it only using while(true) that a server can be created, and if it does then will it not create a out of memory exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `while(true)` loop there is no out of memory exception if you dont have memory leaks in your loop. If you would try to run endless with recursion, this would happen at some point due to the growing callstack.

If a program has to run endless (or until some condition, but not a fixed amount of operations), it needs an endless loop, sometimes it is called event-loop to sound more fancy, but most programs have it somewhere.

Technically you can also write `for(;;)` aswell, which can theoretically be better in unoptimized environments, because there is no condition that has to be checked, but most compilers will optimize the `while(true)`anyways.